# VBA evaluate an adjacent cell before pasting inside of a loop

Tags: vba, excel

The following VBA code in excel is copying a section from a sheet ("Copy model") and pasting it into another sheet ("paste model") first available blank row.

My Inputs sheet has a column with names and a second column to the with level. The code pastes the name in "B3", but I have a level that I manually change in B4 so the model roles up at a different level.

I want to adjust the code to evaluate whether the level has changed, and if so, paste the new adjacent level.

Inputs is set up like (starting at "B172"). I want to evaluate column "C" (PL/ML) before pasting the value from C. This speeds up my code a lot.

Paste (name) into "B3"
Paste (Level) into "B4" if the adjacent level does not = what is already in "B4"

```
(Col B)  (Col C)  
Jim       PL
Bod       PL
Todd      PL
Nick      ML
Steve     ML
```

The VBA:

```
Sub Loopfor()

    Sheets("Inputs").Select

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("B172:B187")

    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Copy Model")

    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Paste model")

    ''Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do

        For Each cell In rng

            cell.Copy
            Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            copySheet.Range("A143:W264").Copy
            pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Sheets("Inputs").Select

        Next cell

    Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

    ''Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And what's happening with your code now? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Currently no error and it works as it should, but I want to add an evaluation of column "C" (adjacent value to B that is currently selected within the loop) and paste the value into "B4" if it is different. Example would be "B4" would show PL until Nick, then the VBA would copy and paste ML into "B4". I dont want to paste it each time because that causes a lot of calculations to kick off, slowing down my loop significantly.

Comment: You can turn off automatic calculations before the loop starts and turn it back on after the loop completes. In fact, you probably _should_ do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are saying that each time the value in column C changes (as you scan from top to bottom), you want to put the new value in B4. To do that, put the following code inside the loop:

```
If cell.OffSet(0,1) <> cell.OffSet(-1,1) Then
    cell.OffSet(0,1).Copy
    Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If
```

Comment: This worked perfect. I did a little reading on the cell.offset and it seems to be pretty versatile. I'm sure I will be using this more in the future with multilevel reporting. Thanks!